# How to count specific value from multiple columns which references value from another table

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have two tables looking like below.

Table history :

```
+------+------+------+-----+------+------+
| fir  | sec  | thi  | fou | fif  | six  |
+------+------+------+-----+------+------+
|   10 |   23 |   29 |  33 |   37 |   40 |
|    9 |   13 |   21 |  25 |   32 |   42 |
|   11 |   16 |   19 |  21 |   27 |   31 |
|   14 |   27 |   30 |  31 |   40 |   42 |
|   16 |   24 |   29 |  40 |   41 |   42 |
|   14 |   15 |   26 |  27 |   40 |   42 |
|    2 |    9 |   16 |  25 |   26 |   40 |
|    8 |   19 |   25 |  34 |   37 |   39 |
|    2 |    4 |   16 |  17 |   36 |   39 |
|    9 |   25 |   30 |  33 |   41 |   44 |
|    1 |    7 |   36 |  37 |   41 |   42 |
|    2 |   11 |   21 |  25 |   39 |   45 |
|   22 |   23 |   25 |  37 |   38 |   42 |
|    2 |    6 |   12 |  31 |   33 |   40 |
|    3 |    4 |   16 |  30 |   31 |   37 |
```

Table stats:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |
```

So table history has 6 columns. All 6 columns have different values and can be filled with values from 1 to 45.
Table stats has id column from 1 to 45.

What i want is count "id" values from table history and have another column as count as a result.

I have tried

```
select id from stats as num right join (select count(*) as count from history where fir = num.id OR sec = num.id OR thi = num.id OR fou = num.id OR fif = num.id OR six = num.id) as r
```

but didn't work.

Can i have the result as i want with one query?

Comment: I suggest changing your table design and moving all six columns into just _one_ column, with a new second column which maintains the source of the data.  The query you are asking us for, given your current data design, would be very ugly.

Comment: Are the numbers in each column unique?

Comment: @Nick No they are not unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a left join between the "calendar" `stats` table and a union of your current data.

```sql
SELECT
    s.id,
    COUNT(t.val) AS count
FROM stats s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT fir AS val FROM history UNION ALL
    SELECT sec FROM history        UNION ALL
    SELECT thi FROM history        UNION ALL
    SELECT fou FROM history        UNION ALL
    SELECT fif FROM history        UNION ALL
    SELECT six FROM history
) t
    ON s.id = t.val
GROUP BY
    s.id;
```

Note that here we bring all six columns into a single logical column before doing the overlap check with `stats`.  That we need to do this union implies that maybe your table design should actually just have *one* logical column, with a second column which maintains the data source for each point.

### Demo

Comment: Was just making a demo so I've added it to your answer (hope you don't mind)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It worked just as I wanted

Comment: @Nick The obvious question how is how on Earth did you come up with a demo so quickly?  It took me literally 5 minutes of furious typing...probably the ugliest setup in months.

Comment: "Text to DDL" is your friend... that's why I like db-fiddle although sometimes its necessary to copy over to dbfiddle as db-fiddle doesn't have enough variety of DBMS available.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just an idea but you can use UNION, but maybe there is better solution

```
SELECT s.ID, COUNT(his.x) AS Counted
FROM stats s
JOIN
(SELECT fir AS x FROM history
UNION
SELECT sec AS x FROM history
UNION
SELECT thi AS x FROM history
UNION
SELECT fou AS x FROM history
UNION
SELECT fif AS x FROM history
UNION
SELECT six AS x FROM history) AS his ON s.ID=his.x
GROUP BY s.ID
```